# Setting position and look direction of a GameObject

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm making a bendable game object comprised of a number of bones. The bones positions are calculated using some joints and some maths and that is all working as expected. But I am struggling to rotate the bones to face the correct direction. I'm settings the bones positions like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= bonesCount; i++ ){
    Vector3 newPosition = someFunction();
    bones[i].transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

And that works correctly:

[image: 1]

But when the bendable object bends the bones retain their original rotation:

[image]

I thought I could use `Transform.LookAt` on the bone at position `i` to look at the bone at position `i + 1` but this gives strange results:

[image: 3]

It seems like it's an issue with using the wrong axis (up, right or forward). I see `Transform.LookAt` accepts a second argument for `worldUp` but I haven't figured out how that works.

Any suggestions? Is `Transform.LookAt` the correct method to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the everything is working, except that the bones are made in such a way that the forward axis is not the one you'd expect, so that they don't "look at" each other.

A very lazy solution would be, after you execute `LookAt`, on the same object, make a `Rotate` of 90 degrees. It's probably going to be on the X axis, but it depends how your scene is laid out.

Comment: Thanks, the very lazy solution works. I'll look at fixing the bones

Comment: @eskimo just a tip, if you import them as meshes from another program, you can rotate the object in that program and export them again, this should fix the issue without the `Rotate`